# "Pair words Extractor" - Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I am using Regular Expression in Python to extract "And" Words. Meaning, words that are separated by and.

For example

- banking and finance
- profit and loss

Effort so far:

```
import re
read = open("sample.txt", "r")
regex = re.compile('(?:\S+\s)?\S*and\S*(?:\s\S+)?')
f=open('write.txt','w')
for line in read:
    words = regex.findall(line)
    for word in words:
        f.write(str(word)+'\n')
f.close()
```

This code seems to work well but finds and inside words such as commands.

So I used this Regular Expression

```
regex = re.compile('a-zA-Z]+\s?\S*and\S*\s+[a-zA-Z]+')
```

which works well in website but returns only word and without the preceding word and succeeding word as output inside python.

My intention is to find words separated by and inside a document.

Input

```
This is a sample text to find profit and loss. It should also find banking and finance. But it should not find commands.
```

Current output

- profit and loss.
- banking and finance.
- find commands.

Expected out put

- profit and loss
- banking and finance

Comment: What is your expected output for `banking and finance profit and loss`? Is it just a split by `and`?

Comment: No they are separate.. Amended the question.

Comment: Your regex uses `\S*and\S*`. Are you perhaps also expecting to match stuff like "strong brandy burns" ?

Comment: That' exactly what I don't want and want to avoid it for sure. Is there a way to avoid it. I need to just sense words separated by and. not and occurring within a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Just use the following regex:

```
\S+\sand\s\S+
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/fKLSar/1)

The issue was the `\S*` you added around the `and`. That matches any number of non-whitespace characters around the "and", which would match words like "brandy".

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
\w+(?=\sand\s)|(?<=\sand\s)\w+
```

Which is:

- Some word (`\w+`) matched only where it precedes `\sand\s` with a positive lookahead assertion, OR
- Some workd (`\w+`) matched only where it follows `\sAnd\s` with a positive look-behind assertion

The positive lookbehind needs a string of fixed length so you can't do `(?<=\s+and\s+)` so this solution assumes all the spacing is single spaces.

[Tested](https://regex101.com/r/jXKfYp/2) at regex101.com

[image]

### Edit

Further to the update in the question to get the **something** ***and*** **something else** as a three-word phrase you can try:

```
\w+(?:\s+and\s+)\w+
```

[Tested](https://regex101.com/r/RlosBh/1) with this output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Effort, How to include and between those words as shown in my expected output?

Comment: See the edit please - I answered originally based on different interpretation of your question before you posted an example

Comment: Thanks for the effort once again. Exactly solves the problem.